# Displaying a varying element within a PHP loop

Tags: php, loops, echo

I have a blog with 3 posts per page, and I'd like to show a single advert above each post.

The posts are selected from a MySQL table using PHP, and I can get the posts to echo out propely, but is there a way of showing different adverts within the loop?

Here is my code, and an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$ad_1 = "Advert 1";
$ad_2 = "Advert 2";
$ad_3 = "Advert 3";

$posts .= "

    <div class=\"postDivide\"></div>
    <div class=\"advert\"> $ad_1 then $ad_2 then $ad_3 </div> // Here Is The Problem
    <div class=\"postDivide\"></div>
    <div class=\"post\">
        // Post Content
    </div>

";

echo $posts;
```

Is there a correct way of showing each advert?

Comment: Surely you get your posts from a DB and therefore show them in a while loop which is getting one row at a time from your result set, right?

Comment: `Post Content` comes from a `post` table in the Database. `$ad_1 - _3` are static as I want to be able to change them according to who's advertising with me at that moment.

Comment: @WayneFA If you want to randomize the adverts, then putting them into an array and using a pseudo random number function to get each advert number would be probably be your best solution. If no randomness is required, a simple for loop would suffice.

Comment: @areuz, I'm primarily using Google Adsense so I can only show a particular advert once per page, so it's not really a case of it being random, just a different advert above each of the three posts.

Comment: Then put the ad names in an array. place them using the same loop as gets your posts

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Thanks, I'll look into arrays